# Send Image to PHP with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, filesize, file-type

I have a question again.
I wanted to know it is possible that I send pictures via AJAX to a PHP file.
what am I supposed to write the data into images arrive as an image rather than text

```
<form onsubmit="sendWithAjax()">
    <label>File:
        <input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" />
</form>

sendWithAjax(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: ? ? ?
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send data (file,image) to server via AJAX directly.

You must use some frameworks like: http://www.plupload.com/, http://valums.com/ajax-upload/, or you can read more here -> http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to send pictures to a particular PHP page to elaborate them.

Answer (score 0):

There's various ready-made plugins on doing file upload on jquery.

Doing this kind of uploading hacks is not an enjoyable experience, so people enjoy using ready-made solutions.

Here're a few:

http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/jquery-image-upload-and-crop-for-php/

http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/

You can search more from jquery's plugin -site.

Comment: That second link is definitely not an upload demo.